# Using spyder with virtualenv

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I am a newbie to `Python` and wrapping my head around some basic concepts. I come from `PHP` background. Following is a definition/breakdown of the problem I am facing:

I installed `anaconda`, which had a whole bunch of libraries and tools installed into my system. This is kind of my "master python environment"

Then I created and loaded a `virtualenv`. In this virtualenv I loaded a few packages I wanted like `pip install simplekml`, `pip install ipython`

Now I fired open `spyder` and in the iPython console I tried to `import simplekml` and it gave me an import error. I read about this issue online and it said within spyder I need to point to the python in my virtualenv (using tools > preferences > python interpreter) or I should do a `pip install spyder` from my virtualenv and use that version.

I tried both. I installed spyder in my virtualenv and then in the iPython console when I `import simplekml` I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplekml'
```

If I go to the terminal and open iPython and type the same then it works fine. How can I have that terminal loaded to spyder?

I have been struggling with this for hours so any help you provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't mix `anaconda` with `virtualenv`, use one or the other but not both

Comment: That's right. Please google for *conda environments* and learn how to use them instead of virtualenv. I think that should solve your problems.

Comment: I installed Spyder in every each of my virtualenvs and it works fine. Of course, I don't claim it is the best approach...

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @carlos-cordoba said in his comment. If you have anaconda installed I suggest you create an anaconda environment as so:

```
conda create --name pyflakes spyder simplekml ipython
```

This will create an environment `pyflakes` with spyder, simpleklm and ipython installed.

Then you just have to activate the environment with `source activate pyflakes` or `activate pyflakes` if you are on windows and run spyder from there.

For more information on anaconda environments, see the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html).

EDIT: Add virtualenv example.

To user virtualenv this should work:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ cd my_project_folder
$ virtualenv my_project
$ source my_project/bin/activate
$ pip install spyder simpleklm ipython
```

[Source](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I will try that. I do have a followup question though: Can I do same thing using virtualenv? The reason I bring virtualenv up is because there is also another box in which I need to run stuff, but that does not have conda (I cannot install there for other reasons), but it only has virtualenv. I want to get spyder working on that box with simplekml...

Comment: @UndefinedVariable I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it fails complaining that there is already a (global) spyder: `Requirement already satisfied: spyder in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Any idea how to force an installation of a second local spyder in my virtual env?

Comment: @mcExchange You can use `pip --user install`.

Comment: after installing spyder inside venv, how to access and start that spyder instance instead of the default anaconda one.

Comment: I recommend you rather switch to Anaconda https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html Otherwise once you run the `activate` command you're in that environment and if you run `spyder` it should start the one from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need a spyder.ini file different for each virtual environment.
In this file, spyder saves the python interpreter to use, among other things.
I didn't find a command line option to specify which spyder.ini to use so I created a small bash script:

`` enter code here`echo "Starting spyder with my spyder.ini..."
    cp ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini temp.spyder.ini
    cp /spyder.ini ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini
    echo "Starting spyder..."
    /usr/bin/spyder3 --new-instance -p 
    echo "Spyder closed. Restoring original spyder.ini"
    cp ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini /spyder.ini
    cp temp.spyder.ini ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini
    rm temp.spyder.ini ``


I save it in the bin folder of my virtual environments as spyder3 so when I call spyder3 it will first replace the sypder.ini for the one I want and restore the original one when I close spyder. 
The -p  part is optional.